# Match high and low numbers based on number in-between

Tags: php, mysql

Greetings,

I am planning a PHP and MySQL based app that will help in locating the correct page for a particular address in a map book. The map book uses a high and low address range to place sections of a street or highway in the book, each section with its own page (or sub-section of a page).

The user will enter the street address, house number separate from street name, and the desired result is to print details including the map page. What would be the best way to determine the corresponding high and low range based on the house number given in MySQL?

The table will be similar to this:
**id**, **street_name**, **low_address**, **high_address**, **map_page**

An example entry would be:
**1**, **Elm Street**, **1**, **100**, **30**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hate it when I end up posting my own solution, but MySQL's BETWEEN function fit the bill for this. Here is what i ended up with:

**MySQL Prepared Statement**

```
SELECT * FROM dispatch WHERE streetName = ? AND ? BETWEEN lowAddress AND highAddress LIMIT 1
```

**PHP**

```
$getInfo->execute(array($streetName, $houseNum));
```